# Can I have a server web app layer get an accessToken with oauth, vimeo, and scribe?

Tags: oauth, vimeo, scribe

I want to build a java web app which can be queried via ajax to ask for a various vimeo data like albums, videos, etc. The browser client side will then use this information to create a vimeo player with the data like the video url, sizes, etc. I don't want each user to have to verify access to vimeo, I want the server to act as the middle man to n users on browsers.

I started using the scribe api to oauth and at first I thought after I get a authorization url I could copy that into a browser then get a verifier code and hardwire the request token and verifier code into the service.getAccessToken() call.  This worked fine for my testing. however, when I returned the next day the request token I hardwired stopped working with a 401 - possibly expired oauth token.

So if the token can expire my question is do I have to get a new access token for every user session and check to see if it's expired with some frequency?  If I have to get a new access token with every user, then how would the server get the verifier code? Normally a user would go thru the browser pages and get the verifier code that way but it seems like there should be a way to allow the server to get this verifier code. Seems like I could write some java network code to parse and post these pages but that just doesn't sound right.

I'm new to oauth and the vimeo api so I could be thinking about this in the wrong way so alternative directions would be appreciated too.

Thanks,
Miro

Comment: The Vimeo OAuth tokens do not expire unless created via XAuth. What was the exact error message you received with the 401 error?

Comment: All I see in the response in the TokenExtractorImpl.extract() for the the response is: '401 Unauthorized - Permission Denied - The oauth_token passed was either not valid or has expired.' I'm using oAuth and I previously created the request token and got the verifier by pasting in the authorization url returned the first time I ran the class, then I hardwired the oauth_token & oauth_token_secret that I retrieved from the original request token and used those to directly create the Token obj. I saw one post that said the upload tokens are permanent but nothing about all others.

Comment: Request tokens and verifiers are extremely short lived. Every single authentication attempt needs to request a new Request token and Verifier. If you need more help, you can contact Vimeo directly at https://vimeo.com/help/contact with the tokens you are using, and they can help identify the problem.